# How to use different time zones in Angularjs Application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

I am developing an angular js application. I use dates. I need to provide a option to user to select the timezone? User can select local timezone, UTC or any other timezone from dropdown.

I want to change every occurrence of the Date to the selected timezone date depending on the selection of the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Moment.JS makes this so incredibly simple. You don't have to worry about offsets or anything.  It takes care of it all for you.  Check out the docs [here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)